# Android How to programatically determine which XML layout my app is using?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-xml

I want be be able to log the screen size the app is on to make it easier for me to get the layouts perfect for the different android screen sizes. I have implemented a class called layoutSizeAcitivty with the following code:

```
    public class LayoutSizeActivity extends SherlockActivity{

public void LayoutSize(){
    //Determine screen size
    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) 
    {     
        Log.d("Screen Size: ", "LARGE");
    }
    else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {     
        Log.d("Screen Size: ", "NORMAL");
    } 
    else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {     
        Log.d("Screen Size: ", "SMALL");
    }
    else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {     
        Log.d("Screen Size: ", "XLARGE");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("Screen Size: ","UNKNOWN_CATEGORY_SCREEN_SIZE");
    }

    //Determine density
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int density = metrics.densityDpi;

    if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
        Log.d("Screen Density: ","HIGH");
    }
    else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
        Log.d("Screen Density: ","MEDIUM");
    }
    else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW) {
        Log.d("Screen Density: ","LOW");
    }
    else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {
        Log.d("Screen Density: ","XHIGH");
    }
    else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH) {
        Log.d("Screen Density: ","XXHIGH");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("Screen Density: ","UNKNOWN_CATEGORY");
    }
}

}
```

Then in my first activity in the onCreate method I add this:

```
private LayoutSizeActivity layoutSize;
layoutSize = new LayoutSizeActivity();
layoutSize.LayoutSize();
```

For some reason my LayoutSizeActivity.LayoutSize() returns a null pointer exception. Anyone got any Ideas to why that is? Thanks

Comment: _"my LayoutSizeActivity.LayoutSize() returns a null pointer exception"_ On which line?

Comment: The first if statement in LayoutSizeActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private LayoutSizeActivity layoutSize;
layoutSize = new LayoutSizeActivity();
```

You can NOT create an instance of an `Activity` using `new`. Don't ever try it, it will NEVER work.

The only way you can create an `Activity` is with `startActivity(...)` or one of the similar methods such as `startActivityForResult(...)` etc.

[Activity class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

[Activities Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

[Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)

Comment: so create a new intent in LayoutSizeActivity and start it in my first activity?

Comment: No, create a new `Intent` in first `Activity` and use it to start `LayoutSizeActivity`. The problem is you're going to want a result returned which would mean using `startActivityForResult` which gets more complicated. Why don't you just put the code in the first `Activity` or use a helper class and pass it a `Context`.

Comment: I've moved it into my first class. For further notice, I would create a new intent in first activity to start my LayoutSizeActivity, then would I have to create a new intent to return back to my first activity?

Comment: There are several ways to do it - either use `SharedPreferences` to store the result or if you use `startActivityForResult`, modify the `Intent` in `LayoutSizeActivity`, call finish() and in first `Activity` use `onActivityResult(...)` method. As I said, this is more complex. In saying that - an `Activity` isn't just a general purpose class and shouldn't be used as one - this is something very important you need to understand about Android fundamentals.

Comment: I see. By Activity isn't just a general purpose class, do you mean I should rename it as a helper class such as LayoutSizeHelper? or is there more to it?

Comment: If you stop it from extending `Activity` then yes, rename it to something which will prevent confusion. An `Activity` is basically a UI framework designed for displaying a UI and allowing interaction with the user (button presses etc etc) - if you don't have a UI then you don't need an `Activity`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but what if the code needed inside the class needs the class to extend from activity. E.g inside the `LayoutSizeActivity`, I use `getResources`. without extending from `Activity`, I get errors on it. Thanks

Comment: Another example I have is I have a class called `SherlockHelper`. Here I also extend from `SherlockActivity` and without that the class is pointless and won't work. This class actually uses a static method so I don't have to create a new instance of it. but I obviously can't get rid of the `extends SherlockActivity`

Comment: If you need to use something like `getResources()` pass in a `Context` and use that. As for your other comment NEVER create `public static` methods (or fields) in any class which extends `Activity` - seriously,  at some point down the line your code will crash and burn. Please do some more research on Android app fundamentals and the `Activity` class. See my edit with links.

Comment: OK, glad to help. Sorry if it sounds like there are a whole load of restrictions but the `Activity` class and a few more android-specific classes need to be treated differently to usual Java classes. Once you've grasped those concepts it gets a lot easier and your code will be more robust and reliable.

Comment: I'll look into it a bit more now I think, didn't really get the concept of it tbh. my mentallity at the moment is if it works then thats great lol. But I see where your coming from, will read up on it more. one of the problems I've got is I don't really get what context is, I've read and read about it but just can't grasp what it's actually for and what it does. I just thought it was the state of the application, which I assume is wrong?

Comment: To be honest with you...after over 3 years of programming for Android, I still don't quite get what a `Context` really is either. :D All I know is it implements a suite of methods for accessing resources, file system objects etc etc and `Activity` is an indirect sub-class of it. As a result an `Activity` either directly inherits `Context` methods or provides overridden versions of the `Context` methods. Because of this you can pass a `Context` instance from an `Activity` to a helper by doing something like `myHelper.doSomething(this)`